# Style en Android incompatibles

Tags: android

Buenas,

Antes de nada perdonad que soy nueva con Android. Es mi segunda aplicación.

El problema que tengo es que con Android Studio creo un proyecto con Navigation Drawer Activity.

Después creo una Activity en blanco e introduzco lo siguiente ya que quiero poner una barra con una serie de botones:

```
    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
06-28 13:39:13.880 1192-1192/com.example.shokimc.proyecto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shokimc.proyecto, PID: 1192
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shokimc.proyecto/com.example.shokimc.proyecto.Escaneo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.shokimc.proyecto.Escaneo.onCreate(Escaneo.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Yo creo que es debido a incompatibilidad de styles, pero ando un poco perdida. Este es mi style.xml:

```xml
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Mi Mainactivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_devices));
mHandler = new Handler();

// Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.      Then you can
// selectively disable BLE-related features.
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}

// Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
// BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
        (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

// Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
    return;
}
// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
// See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Prueba con getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_devices));

Comment: @Webserveis Me sigue saliendo error =(

Comment: Creo que el error es usar getActionBar, prueba con getSupportActionBar
miActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);            
setSupportActionBar(miActionBarToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");

Comment: Pon más código de tu onCreate, de como obtienes la toolbar

Comment: @Shokimic creo saber que sucede pero de que extiende tu activity?

Comment: @Elenasys extiende de un ListActivity. Creo que no es compatible, y tengo que poner un AppCompat pero no se cambiar lo que tengo por un listview en el layout :(

Comment: Prueba en el manifest más rápido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de usar `getActionBar()` debes usar `getSupportActionBar()` y la activity que extienda de `AppCompatActivity`

Yo uso lo siguiente para establecer el título:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if (toolbar != null) {
    toolbar.setTitle("ActionBar Title");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("Subtitle");
}
```

Comment: Este es el onCreate

Comment: He probado lo que me has puesto, pero aún no me funciona :(

Answer (score 0):

El problema es por que tu actividad extiende de un `ListActivity`, para poder realizar esto:

```
Actionbar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setTitle("Hola StackOverflow!");
```

**tu `Activity` debe extender de [`FragmentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html), [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) o [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).**

Te recomiendo cambiar a cualquiera de las 3 por ejemplo:

`MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

El cambio es sencillo, dentro de `setContentView()` del método `onCreate()` agrega el layout que contenga el `ListView`.